# How to prove equality impossible

Tags: coq, idris

```
1 subgoal
a, b : Tipe
H : TApp a b = a
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

(where TApp is a constructor)

In Idris this can be proved with `\Refl => impossible` but I haven't managed to write any proof for it in Coq.

Is there an easy way to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove it by `induction a.`. The idea is that the induction principle for `Tipe` encodes the fact that its values are finite in size, while the `TApp a b = a` assumption allows you to construct an infinite value, but these are somewhat indirect consequences from the raw facts you have, hence you need to work a bit for it. An extension of Coq to derive and use such occurs-check lemmas automatically would definitely be possible.